# How do I implement rank function for nearest values for a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking, rank

```
df.head():

                      run_time match_datetime         country                league             home_team                  away_team
0   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-06          Russia       FNL 2 - Group 2             Yenisey 2          Lokomotiv-Kazanka
1   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07          Russia          Youth League              Ural U19  Krylya Sovetov Samara U19
2   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-08           World         Club Friendly                Alaves                    Al Nasr
3   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-09           China            Jia League     Chengdu Rongcheng          Shenyang Urban FC
4   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-06           China          Super League              Wuhan FC       Tianjin Jinmen Tiger
5   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07  Czech Republic            U19 League     Sigma Olomouc U19                Karvina U19
6   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-08          Russia          Youth League  Konoplev Academy U19            Rubin Kazan U19
7   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-09           World         Club Friendly         Real Sociedad                      Eibar
```

desired df

```
                      run_time match_datetime         country                league             home_team                  away_team
0   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-06          Russia       FNL 2 - Group 2             Yenisey 2          Lokomotiv-Kazanka
1   2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07          Russia          Youth League              Ural U19  Krylya Sovetov Samara U19
4   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-06           China          Super League              Wuhan FC       Tianjin Jinmen Tiger
5   2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07  Czech Republic            U19 League     Sigma Olomouc U19                Karvina U19
```

How do i use `rank` function to filter only the 2 nearest `match_datetime` dates for every `run_time` value.
i.e. desired dataframe will be a filtered dataframe that will have all the nearest 2 `match_datetime` values for every `run_time`

Comment: If the data is sorted by `match_datetime`: `df.groupby('run_time').head(2)`

Comment: @mozway. I reopened the question because the answer is not so obvious :)

Comment: @Corralien sure, then the description could be improved

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Using `rank` instead of `head`:

```
diff = pd.to_datetime(df['run_time']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['match_datetime'])).abs()
out = df.loc[diff.groupby(df['run_time']).rank(method='dense') <= 2]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                     run_time match_datetime         country         league          home_team                  away_team
1  2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07          Russia   Youth League           Ural U19  Krylya Sovetov Samara U19
2  2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-08           World  Club Friendly             Alaves                    Al Nasr
4  2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-06           China   Super League           Wuhan FC       Tianjin Jinmen Tiger
5  2021-08-06 00:04:36.326391     2021-08-07  Czech Republic     U19 League  Sigma Olomouc U19                Karvina U19
```

**Alternative**

You can use:

```
diff = pd.to_datetime(df['run_time']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['match_datetime'])) \
                              .abs().sort_values()
out = df.loc[diff.groupby(df['run_time']).head(2).index].sort_index()
```

Comment: You have another alternative with `nsmallest`: `out = df.loc[diff.groupby(df['run_time']).nsmallest(2).index.levels[1]].sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

I am somehow afraid that the `pandas.DataFrame.rank` method can't do this. But `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` can do this, if you use `pandas.DataFrame.head` with it.

Assuming you have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.randint(0, 3, 10), np.random.rand(10)]).transpose(), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

And that you want to keep `max_num_per_example = 2` representatives of each unique values in the column `df['a']`:

```py
max_num_per_example = 2
df.groupby(['a']).head(max_num_per_example)
```

yields

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.0 | 0.058084 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.866176 |
| 2 | 2.0 | 0.601115 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0.020584 |
| 7 | 1.0 | 0.212339 |

This is the same as you would get if you to the naive approach:

```py
max_idx_per_example = 2
idx_to_keep = []
for el_uq in df['a'].unique():
    lg = el_uq == df['a']
    for i, idx in enumerate(lg[lg].index):
        if i < max_idx_per_example:
            idx_to_keep.append(idx)
        else:
            break
df_new = df.iloc[idx_to_keep]
```

Which underlines the power of `pandas` =)